# Tabulator Multiple Filter in the same Column (show dropbox)

Tags: tabulator

Hi I'm trying to create a headerFilter that allows multiple filter selection in the same column. Something like **headerFilter:"select"** but showing probably a dropdown to select which values don you want to filter. 
I'm think I need to use a **headerFilterFunc** but I'm not sure how to pass the selected values. 
Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this I posted with my question about <select> and movableColumns ...

https://jsfiddle.net/hsvyc1a8/

```
...
```

Comment: That helps for numeric values but what about nominals? Like certain categories etc. Should it follow kind of the same process?

Comment: Yes, that is what I do. I have a few slightly different variations based on the need