# How can you get Tabulator to use Select2 header filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, tabulator

Following the example [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/edit#edit-custom), we've been trying for over a week to get Tabulator working with a Select2 header filter. There is a JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n73f2Lsw/) with all the pieces. It seems like the Tabulator filter (which are really just editors) onRendered() function is not even getting called because the console log we have inside it never gets logged.

The select element itself shows up in the header filter, but never gets the Select2 object applied (probably because the onRendered seems to not even be called). If we put the Select2 object outside the onRendered function, it get applied, but then the filter does not get applied after selection is made. There are no console or other errors and we've followed the Tabulator 'example' to the letter, so we are not sure what to try next.

Does anyone know how to get a basic Select2 header filter functioning with Tabulator?

```
var tableData = [{
    id: "1",
    topic: "1.1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    topic: "2.2"
  },
];

var select2Editor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
  var editor = document.createElement("select");
  var selData = [{
    id: '1.1',
    text: "One"
  }, {
    id: "2.2",
    text: "Two"
  }, {
    id: "3.3",
    text: "Three"
  }, ];

  onRendered(function() {
    // TODO: map tracks to id and text
    console.log('rendered');

    $(editor).select2({
      data: selData,
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      width: '100%',
      minimumInputLength: 0,
      //allowClear: true,
    });
    
    $(editor).on('change', function(e) {
      success($(editor).val());
    });


    $(editor).on('blur', function(e) {
      cancel();
    });

  });


  return editor
};


var columns = [{
  title: "ID",
  field: "id"
}, {
  title: "Topic",
  field: "topic",
  headerFilter: select2Editor,
}, ];


var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
  placeholder: "No Data Found.",
  layout: "fitData",
  data: tableData,
  columns: columns,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to both Tabulator and select2 and I think this is possibly a bad way to do it but it seems like it miiight work.

If you want to use select2 with text input elements, it looks like you need to use the full package.

https://jsfiddle.net/dku41pjy/

```
var tableData = [{
    id: "1",
    topic: "1.1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    topic: "2.2"
  },
];

var columns = [{
  title: "ID",
  field: "id"
}, {
  title: "Topic",
  field: "topic",
  headerFilter: 'select2Editor'
}, ];

var awaiting_render = [];

function do_render({ editor, cell, success, cancel, editorParams }) {
  console.log('possibly dodgy onrender');
    var selData = [{
    id: '',
    text: "-- All Topics --"
  }, {
    id: '1.1',
    text: "One"
  }, {
    id: "2.2",
    text: "Two"
  }, {
    id: "3.3",
    text: "Three"
  }, ];
  
  $(editor).select2({
    data: selData,
    //allowClear: true,
  });

  $(editor).on('change', function(e) {
    console.log('chaaaange')
    success($(editor).val());
  });


  $(editor).on('blur', function(e) {
    cancel();
  });
      
}
function render_awaiting() {
    var to_render = awaiting_render.shift();
  do_render(to_render);
  if(awaiting_render.length > 0)
    render_awaiting();
}

Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("edit", "editors", {
    select2Editor:function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
      console.log(cell);
      var editor = document.createElement("input");
      editor.type = 'text';
      awaiting_render.push({ editor, cell, success, cancel, editorParams });

      return editor
    },
});

var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
  placeholder: "No Data Found.",
  layout: "fitData",
  data: tableData,
  columns: columns,
  tableBuilt:function(){
    render_awaiting();
  },
});
```

Edit: my suspicion is that onRendered only gets fired when these edit elements are used in cells to sope with the transition between showing just data and showing an editable field.

Comment: Well that does seem to work, but only with the element being an input - which is why we went down this path to begin with. We cannot style the input elements text and we need to format the selections, but NOT have that formatting show up once selected, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539421/how-can-you-format-a-tabulator-select-based-header-filters-options

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dku41pjy/1/ now has the options in italics, is that the sort of thing you wanted?

Comment: Example with arbitrary option formatting: https://jsfiddle.net/dku41pjy/3/

Comment: I am accepting the answer and awarding the bounty because per this literal question the answers does work. I also appreciate the extra effort on formatting. There are still some issues though. Clicking the select also causes the column to sort. Also it duplicates a lot of data to make the formatting work.

Comment: @DDurham, https://jsfiddle.net/s9muwdc6/2/ should no longer have the issue where clicking the select causes the column to sort. The way the formatting works can be controlled by editing formatState. If you can derive the formatted version just from the text field in the data, then you don't need the formatted version, you can just add some HTML to the text. e.g. the version in https://jsfiddle.net/dku41pjy/1/