# Multiselect style in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I do have a multiselect header filter in tabulator created according to this guide: [How do I create a multi-select header filter in tabulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218807/how-do-i-create-a-multi-select-header-filter-in-tabulator)

I am lost with styling that multiselect input field. Would you please advise, how can I change the style to i.e. chosen, select2, bootstrap, or any other custom style?

I have tried to to assign css class to that column header, which works, but the data are not dynamically changed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

My current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>List of processing items</title>

<meta charset=UTF-8>
<?php include 'header.php';?>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div id="tabulator"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

const processingTypeTypes = ['TASK', 'WORKFLOW'];
function multiSelectHeaderFilter(cell) {
  var values = processingTypeTypes;
  const filterFunc = (rowData) => {
    return values.includes(rowData['processingType']);
  }
  const getSelectedValues = (multiSelect) => {
    var result = [];
    var options = multiSelect && multiSelect.options;
    var opt;

    for (var i = 0, iLen = options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      opt = options[i];

      if (opt.selected) {
        result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  const onChange = () => {
    var editor = document.getElementById('processingTypeSelector');
    values = getSelectedValues(editor);
    console.log("values: " + values);
    cell.getColumn().getTable().removeFilter(filterFunc);
    cell.getColumn().getTable().addFilter(filterFunc);
  }

  var select = document.createElement("select");
  select.multiple = "multiple";
  select.id = 'processingTypeSelector';
  select.class = "chosen-select";
  select.style = 'width: 100%';
  processingTypeTypes.forEach(processingType => {
    select.innerHTML += "<option id='" + processingType + "' value='" + processingType + "' selected='selected'>" + processingType + "</option>";
  });
  cell.getColumn().getTable().addFilter(filterFunc);
  select.addEventListener('change', onChange);

  return select;
}
</script>

<script>
var tabledata = 
<?php include("include/dummyJson.php"); ?>
;

var table = new Tabulator("#tabulator", {
    layout:"fitColumns",
    headerSort: true,
    tooltips:true,
    placeholder:"No Data. Incorrect input, OR empty response.",
    data:tabledata,
    columns:[
    {title:"Type", field: "processingType", sorter: "string", headerFilter: multiSelectHeaderFilter, headerFilterLiveFilter: false},
    ],
});
</script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling of the list element will not be changed if you styled the column header because the list element is attached directly to the body element and absolutely positioned to below the input element for the select. This approach removes any container overflow issues that would otherwise be present.

If you want to be able to style the lists themselves then you need to override the CSS applied to the classes. *(make sure you add this css after you import your tabulator.css)*

To override anything on the list container you will need:

```css
.tabulator-edit-select-list{
    border:2px solid #f00; //make list have red border
}
```

To override anything on the list items you will need:

```css
.tabulator-edit-select-list .tabulator-edit-select-list-item{
    color:#f00; //make list item have red text
}
```

To override anything on a selected list item you will need:

```css
.tabulator-edit-select-list .tabulator-edit-select-list-item.active{
    background:#f00; //make list item background red when selected
}
```

To override anything on a focused list item you will need:

```css
.tabulator-edit-select-list .tabulator-edit-select-list-item.focused{
    background:#0f0; //make list item background green when focused
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. And thanks for the Tabulator in general, this is great tool! I managed to change style of the multiselect to the bootstrap-miltiselect as you can see in this example: https://codepen.io/vojta-bures/pen/MWjvByM

however, if you click on the multiselect, its expanded in the column row and destroys the view. Can you please suggest how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This happening because the bootstrap-select you are using is appending the list element to the header cell which is causing it to overflow. Usually these sort of select elements have an option to append the list to the body, in a similar way to Tabulator. But Tabulator does already come with a built in multiselect header filter so i am a bit unsure why you would need to build your own one

Comment: Well, if I use tabulatro built in multiselect, then its not working for multiple values selected. See here: https://codepen.io/vojta-bures/pen/YzGxOQd

Comment: That is because you have to set the headerFilterFunc to "in" if you are using a multi select. Because the select then returns an array and you want it to filter by checking if the cells value is "in" the returned array

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, Oli!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you are happy with this would you mind marking the answer as correct so that others can find it easliy